# Azure Monitor B2C User Journeys SigninLogs not showing proper errors

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-log-analytics, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

We are using Azure Monitor Log Analytics workspace to check production issues with Azure B2C User Journeys.

Querying SigninLogs for failed user journeys shows "Invalid Username or Password..." error instead of the actual exception occured for one of the journey steps that calls an API.

App Insights show below error:

[image]

Why does SigninLogs only have generic "Invalid Username or Password" error? How are we going to monitor the exceptions (API connector calls etc.)? happened during user journey using Azure Monitor Log Analytics Workspace

Answer (score 0):

According to the SignIn Log document of Azure AD here :  -

“If a sign-in failed, you can get more information about the reason in the Basic infosection of the related log item. The error code and associated failure reason appear in the details. Because of the complexity of some Azure AD environments, we cannot document every possible error code and resolution. Some errors may require[submitting a support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/how-to-get-support)to resolve the issue. > From this link = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins#sign-in-error-codes”

-But you can copy the error code and try to  find insights on the error code by using this tool :-

https://login.microsoftonline.com/error

Copy your error code number and you get the required information about the error faced by your users or applications.
[image]
You can also refer AAD authorization error document here -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes

Customer statement :- How are we going to monitor the exceptions (API connector calls etc.)? happened during user journey using Azure Monitor Log Analytics Workspace?

After you have enabled Azure log analytics Monitoring for your Azure AD B2C tenant using this document :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/azure-monitor

You can make use of custom ARM templates from this Github repo and use it to get additional logs on Azure AD B2C user journeys:- https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/siem

Example- Template = List of Abandon Journeys:
[image]
In the above example -You can enter the values of Azure Log Analytics workspace, Workbook Id and required values in the template and fetch logs from Azure AD B2C to Azure Log Analytics Workspace and get detailed Dashboard on your User SignUpSignIn journeys.

If you’re using Custom policies and want to get insights on User behaviour in your flow you can enable application insights by adding the instrumentation key from your Azure Application Insights to your custom policy xml file and get insights in your Azure Application insight resource.

Refer Here:-  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/analytics-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

You can also check Audit Logs directly from Azure AD b2c tenant to get information on resources in Azure B2C, Token Issuance, administrator access.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, good general information but I already enabled Log Analytics workspace and used ARM templates from the github SIEM repo. The issue is error codes do not show actual errors, just "invalid username and/or password". App insights exceptions show different errors. Signinlogs do not - thats the issue

Comment: Please raise this concern on [MS Q&A] (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html) or reach out to Microsoft support.